# How to broadcast to socketio from another thread in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, flask-socketio

A `flask_socketio` app is running as a server. In a list managed by the app, there are several instances that inherit `threading.Threads`, each running a mainloop. Once in a while, I would like to signal the `flask-socketio` server to emit a broadcast to a certain room. How could I do this?

I am unable to figure out how to do that as `flask_socketio` is running in a mainloop itself, but I don't have access to this mainloop. Is there a way to have the flask mainloop read from a `Queue`?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to access the `SocketIO` instance for this. Somewhere in your app you have:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app)
```

In the thread from where you want to emit, just import this object and call the `emit` method:

```
from app import socketio
# ...
def emit_to_room(event, data, room):
    socketio.emit(event, data, room=room)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work. The messages don't arrive on the client side.

Comment: I changed the approach so that I'm passing the SocketIO instance to the constructor of my thread instead of importing it, which worked. However, I ran into other problems now which might relate to threading and blocking, which made the complete idea useless.

Comment: Blocking problems can occur if you are using eventlet or gevent with code that use the standard Python threading classes, which are not eventlet/gevent friendly. If you monkey patch the std library you should be fine.